# AngularJS $interval firing twice in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, css-animations

I am building an 'attract loop' directive. The directive will basically take a photo, run an animation, hide that photo, then show the next one in the list.

The first run of the loop works fine. However, when I return to the page, the intervals that govern the animations are firing twice, causing havoc.

To reproduce, go to [Reproduction Link](http://evanmrose.co/projects/dev/coca/app/#/attract), click on the page then wait (1 second) and it will return to the attract loop page automatically and display the error listed above. There are console logs indicating the fact that the $intervals get called twice the second time.

```
.directive('attract', ['$timeout', '$state', '$rootScope', '$interval', function($timeout, $state, $rootScope, $interval){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var slide, $attractWrap, $activeSlide, slideWidth, nextSlide, prevSlide, transition, elemShift;

            $rootScope.$on('restart-loop', function(e){
                console.log('Quipu Reset');
                if(angular.isDefined(scope.step1) || angular.isDefined(scope.step2) || angular.isDefined(scope.step3) || angular.isDefined(scope.step4) || angular.isDefined(scope.step5) || angular.isDefined(scope.step6) ){
                    scope.reset();
                }
            });

            scope.pan = function(obj, type){
                var $obj = $(obj), transition;

                switch(type){
                    case 'diagonal':
                        $obj.css({
                            '-webkit-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            '-moz-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            '-o-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            'transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            'transform': 'translate(-2000px, -1000px)'
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'vertical':
                        $obj.css({
                            '-webkit-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            '-moz-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            '-o-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            'transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            'transform': 'translate(0px, -1000px)'
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'diagonal-reverse':
                        $obj.css({
                            '-webkit-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            '-moz-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            '-o-transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            'transition': 'all 10s ease-in-out',
                            'transform': 'translate(-600px, -1500px)'
                        });
                        break;
                }

            };

            scope.resetTranslate = function(obj, resetLoc, nextImgFlag){
                var $obj = $(obj);
                switch(resetLoc){
                    case 'tl':
                        $obj.css({
                            '-webkit-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            '-moz-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            '-o-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            'transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            'transform': 'translate(0px, 0px)'
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'tr':
                        $obj.css({
                            '-webkit-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            '-moz-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            '-o-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            'transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            'transform': 'translate(-3300px, 0px)'
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'tc':
                        $obj.css({
                            '-webkit-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            '-moz-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            '-o-transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            'transition': 'all 0s ease-in-out',
                            'transform': 'translate(0px, 0px)'
                        });
                        break;
                }

                //if(nextImgFlag !== false){
                    //next image
                    scope.nextImage();
                //}


            };

            scope.nextImage = function(){
                $('#attract-loop').find('.active').removeClass('active').hide().next().addClass('active').show();
            }

            scope.stopStep = function(step){
                console.log($interval.cancel(step));
                return step = undefined;
            }

           scope.reset = function(){
                //flush promises
                scope.step1 = scope.stopStep(scope.step1);
                scope.step2 = scope.stopStep(scope.step2);
                scope.step3 = scope.stopStep(scope.step3);
                scope.step4 = scope.stopStep(scope.step4);
                scope.step5 = scope.stopStep(scope.step5);
                scope.step6 = scope.stopStep(scope.step6);
                scope.resetTranslate('#attract-loop', 'tl', false);
                $('#attract-loop').children().removeClass('active').hide().first().show().addClass('active');
                scope.attractLoopAnimation();
            }

            scope.attractLoopAnimation = function(){
                console.log('Starting Attract Loop');
                if(!angular.isDefined(scope.step1)){
                    scope.step1 = $interval(function(){
                        console.log('Firing step 1 - Initial diagonal pan');
                        scope.pan($('#attract-loop'), 'diagonal');
                    }, 1000, 1);
                }

                if(!angular.isDefined(scope.step2)){
                     scope.step2 = $interval(function(){
                        console.log('Firing step 2 - Reset to top center');    
                        scope.resetTranslate('#attract-loop', 'tc');
                    }, 11000, 1);
                }

                if(!angular.isDefined(scope.step3)){
                    scope.step3 = $interval(function(){
                        console.log('Firing step 3 - Vertical pan');
                        scope.pan($('#attract-loop'), 'vertical'); 
                    }, 13000, 1); 
                }

                if(!angular.isDefined(scope.step4)){
                    scope.step4 = $interval(function(){
                        console.log('Firing step 4 - Reset to top right');
                        scope.resetTranslate('#attract-loop', 'tr');
                    }, 23000, 1); 
                }

                if(!angular.isDefined(scope.step5)){
                    scope.step5 = $interval(function(){
                        console.log('Firing step 5 - Reverse diagonal pan');
                        scope.pan($('#attract-loop'), 'diagonal-reverse');
                    }, 25000, 1);  
                }

                if(!angular.isDefined(scope.step6)){
                    scope.step6 = $interval(function(){
                        console.log('Firing step 6 - Reset loop');
                        scope.reset();
                    }, 35000, 1);
                }

            }


            scope.attractLoopAnimation();



            //set timer to trigger slide function
            //setTimeout(function(){
            //  slide();
            //}, 3000);

            $(elem).click(function(){
                $state.go('about');
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Any takers? Could really use the help

Comment: There's a lot of code here and it's difficult to really see what the problem is. Once common issue is not canceling all the `$interval`s when the directive is unloaded--so things are still firing when you visit another route, and coming back duplicates them. Try adding a handler in the link function--something like `elem.on('$destroy', cleanupIntervals)`. See also this page: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom

Comment: It may be easier to remove the use of `$interval` all together--there doesn't seem to be a a purpose in it, as `reset` cancels them all and then recreates them. Perhaps `$timeout` or simply calling each step as the last finishes will be easier to reason about.

Comment: Tried with $timeout, didn't work. How would I hook into each one finishing? There are animations within each function call, how do I know when they're done aside from calculating the time? @BrandonTilley